# Problem with Splash screen and changing Theme?

Tags: android, styles, android-manifest, splash-screen, android-styles

I added Splash screen. And If I change app theme by `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)` in settings fragment I will redirect to first fragment (main\home fragment). If I remove splash from manifest Everything will be fine! So, what's the problem? May be i've made mistake when create splash window? I want to stay in settings fragment after I change theme.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.***********">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Todo">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/splashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Todo.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Style for splash:

```
<style name="splashScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splashscreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Window Background:

```
layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
<item
    android:gravity="center"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:height="300dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

</layer-list>
```

I'm using

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.1'
```

and Tamplate "Navigation Drawer Actyvity" (Single Activity)

Video:
No splash [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg1lgAdajRo&ab_channel=%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%96%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2),
with splash [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLE7mAmg054&ab_channel=%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you forgot finish your splash activity.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()